# Kinesis Data Firehose set with a web page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Well, I have a web page (PHP) that is running on-premise and it's accessed from different countries. I would like to catch some data and store it somewhere. I can handle internally with the team the data and the format of the file to catch the info. But we would like to get leverage of AWS to store it in S3. So we notice that we need an intermedium layer to avoid use AWS credentials required for S3.

as this page is on the internet and it's consumed by a user thru web for sure we don't want to include anything for credentials embedded in the site. So likely Kinesis data firehose as consumer role could just catch the data send by our page and then internally store it in S3.

**Question**

I see that exist an SDK for Kinesis but it requires AWS credentials. We really need a kind of link where we need the data produced and AWS handles the rest. But I don't know why I require to set up AWS credentials using the SDK. Does it mean then that our website will load and live with our credentials? I don't feel this approach secure. I appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API Gateway Kinesis Proxy to avoid using credentials or even aws-sdk in your webpages.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html

This way you don't need to expose any credentials and control permissions with a role.

If you are worried about having a security issue and if the users are authenticated, you can use custom authorizers to authorize the url.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html

If it is public facing, then just the above integration should work.

Hope it helps.